# How to create Stop watch

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, timer

I have an Ajax call like this:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#formPropiedades', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var content = {}, url = "http://www.xxxxyzzz.com/xxx/yyy/web/ajax.php";    
    $("#dialog1").dialog("open");
    var posting = $.post(url, {
        im_core: 'saveAllAdds',
        idFeed: <?php echo $_POST['idFeed'] ?>,
        pais: <?php echo $pais1?>
    }).done(function(data) {
        if (data == 1)
            $(".overlay-bg1").html("Suces....");
        else
            $(".overlay-bg1").html(data);
    }); 
<?php } ?>  
});
```

And my HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="dialog1" title="Attention!!" style="width:60%">
    <div class="overlay-bg1">Saving the Adds....</div>
</div>
```

The code for opening the jQuery UI Dialogue is like this

```
$(function () {
    $("#dialog1").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "",
            duration: 1000
        },  
    });
});
```

I want to Show a timer in the POPUP which should start when the Ajax call is done and stop when I get the response. It should look like a Stop watch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

before ajax start:

```
var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
```

when you get the response:

```
var nowTime = (new Date()).getTime();
var theTime = nowTime - startTime;
```

**UPDATE:**

with a visual timer [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tf61f6m4/1/)

**UPDATE:**

seconds and minutes [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tf61f6m4/2/)

**UPDATE:**

with number round [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tf61f6m4/3/)

Comment: Sorry for not saying clearly I need to show a timer increasing every second Like in visual .

Comment: @Vikram already update, the startTimer() and stopTimer() in [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tf61f6m4/1/) maybe your need.

Comment: can you tell me how I can show the time in Minutes bcoz I have huge number of adds coming over so it takes few minutes to upload in the Database

Comment: @Vikram  just change the denominator to minute(1000*60), seconds and minutes [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tf61f6m4/2/).

Comment: but it shows decimals many digits after the decimals , Is it possible to round it to 3 digits ? I tried using math.round and then .toFIxed(2) function but won't work

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="timer"></div> //put this div where you want to show the timer

<input type="button" onClick="fireAJAX();"> // firing ajax call
```

Then in your `fireAJAX()` function

```
function fireAJAX()
{
    var counter = 0;
    var interVal = setInterval(function () {
       $('.timer').html(++counter);     
    }, 1000);

    //Start timer and append the counter to 'timer' div every second

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : URL,
        success : function(response){                
             clearInterval(interVal );
             // stop the counter after ajax response
        }
  });
}
```

So everytime when you call `fireAJAX` function, the timer will start from 1

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('submit', '#formPropiedades', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var content = {},
    url="http://www.xxxxyzzz.com/xxx/yyy/web/ajax.php"; 
        var setTimer = setInterval(function(){ //start your timer
        var d = new Date();
        document.getElementById("myDivID").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();//give the id of your div
        },1000);                      
    $("#dialog1").dialog("open");
     var posting = $.post(url, {
            im_core:'saveAllAdds',
            idFeed :<?php echo $_POST['idFeed'] ?>,
            pais:<?php echo $pais1?>
        }).done(function (data) {
            clearInterval(clearInterval); //stop your timer
            if(data==1)
            $(".overlay-bg1").html("Suces....");
            else
            $(".overlay-bg1").html(data);

        }); 
    <?php } ?>  

    });
```